# how to add a SMB (samba) password for a user in Debian, when there is no smbpasswd binary?

Tags: linux, debian, samba, smb, passwd

I have samba installed on a Debian server of mine, and I use libpam-smbpass to keep UNIX and SMB passwords in sync. Passwords are only changed from unix logins via shell at the moment.

However, just now I added a new user and gave it a password. The libpam-smbpass module tells me that:

```
pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user XXX.
```

This is natural, as I most likely need to add an entry to the passwd.tdb file that is used by Samba for authentication before that entry can be changed automatically by pam_smbpass.

However, samba-common in Debian no longer contains the smbpasswd utility!

So, my question is: How should I add a SMB password entry for a newly created user in Debian unstable today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's in the `samba-common-bin` package:  [package page](http://packages.debian.org/sid/samba-common-bin), [filelist](http://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/samba-common-bin/filelist)

Appears this was spun out of `samba-common` with version 2:3.4.0~pre2-1 of the `samba` source package ([changelog](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/s/samba/samba_3.4.5~dfsg-1/changelog)):

> samba  (2:3.4.0~pre2-1) experimental; urgency=low
>
> [ Jelmer Vernooij ]
>     * Split binaries out of samba-common into samba-common-bin.
>       Closes: [#524661](http://bugs.debian.org/524661)

Comment: Perfect, managed to miss that package for some odd reason. Thanks.